# Arduino with Visual C# made software don't properly work

Tags: c#, c, arduino

i'm new here, so i have a question about Arduino and Visual C# software.
I'm making a software which send a "data" to my arduino device through COM5 port and i have a 3 sets of words, ON, OFF and INTER. ON = High up the LED , OFF = Low the LED, and INTER is making it blinking. ON works, OFF works too, but when i press on my software the button to send the INTER data to my arduino is getting the ON signal, so it's stays powered on as the ON data sent.

Here's my arduino code. (I don't think is from my C# software, cause everything else works fine but blinking on sending the INTER word to my char variable doesn't work).

```
int led = 11;
int led13 = 13;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(led13,LOW);
  char data = Serial.read();
  switch (data) 
  {
    case 'ON': digitalWrite(led,HIGH); break;
    case 'OFF': digitalWrite(led,LOW); break;

  }
  data = Serial.read();
  if (data == 'INTER') { inter(); }
}

void inter()
{
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  delay(1600);
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
  delay(1600);

}
```

Comment: Should there be a subsequent (duplicate) call to Serial.read() before you check if (data == 'INTER')?

Comment: I've tried that. I've eliminate that duplicate, and still got no result.

Comment: My original sketch doesn't have that duplicate. I've tried to reread that data char but... same result... I thinking about....that switch case instruction.. i guess the arduino didn't left the switch case and it's going on and on with that switch case instructions... but.. i really don't know what's going on.. I'm thinking to send data in integer variables too see if  those information are distrubing somehow the arduino device.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code structure is wrong for many reasons.

1-**Serial.read();** returns a Char so you only have one char each time you attempt a read  
2-you are using case 'ON': which im not sure how arduino interprets it .
here are some general rules about switch case:

> 1. values for 'case' must be integer or character constants
> 2. List item the order of the 'case' statements is unimportant
> 3. List item the default clause may occur first (convention places it last)      you cannot use expressions or ranges

3- you need to read the whole serial buffer once it's available by using 
while(Serial.avilable()) {   } then you may check if the received string contains or equal to ON/OFF/INTER

I really have no idea what will arduino make of 'INTER' or 'OFF' as single quotes identify a single character